# filter data Firestore with infinite scroll pagination / angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I've implemented an infinite scroll by Jeff Delaney: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/infinite-scroll-firestore-angular/ apparently it's working, but when I tried the filters I had stopped working. How should I focus the filters for a collection with an infinite scroll?

When I try it without this pagination the filters seem to work, even so I do not know if this approach is correct. Any help is appreciated.

Here a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/infinite-scroll-firestore

some pieces of code:

**component.html**

```
<button *ngFor="let categoria of categoriasTest | async" (click)="filtrarData(categoria.nombre)" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mx-1">{{ categoria.nombre }}</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
filtrarData( categoria: Categoria) {
  this.avisosTest = this.fs.filterBy(categoria);
  this.selectedCategoria = categoria;
}
```

**service.ts**

```
filterBy(categoria: Categoria) {
  this.avisosTest = this.afs.collection('avisosTest', ref => ref.where('categoria','==', categoria )).valueChanges()
  return this.avisosTest;
};
```